# How to avoid "should" proposals in technical report?

Tags: conditionals, should

I noticed that I have many sentences where I say that "[this should be done]" because something is missing and something should be done differently.
However, I do not like to be like teaching someone.

Example

> The documentation misses some descriptions of some fields and completely the fields \emph{fileHeader} and \emph{eventHeader}, which should be added there.

How can you say such a should-sentence more positively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your role is here.  Are you writing a review of someone else's technical report?  Or are you documenting the shortcomings of your own work?

In any event, perhaps you could have a separate section within the document that is titled "Future Steps", or "Next Steps", or "Action Items".  This way your suggestions will not seem as negative.  You are instead suggesting follow-on steps that build on the good work already accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

If it's imperative that it needs to be added, then 'should' or 'shall' would be appropriate.

Otherwise:

"Needs to be" .... "Needs to be added there"
"To add more clarity to the \emph{fiileHeader} amd \emph{eventHeader], please include the complete descriptions and fields"